# How do I hide '#StandWithUkraine' in PHPUnit 9.5.20?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have recently upgraded to PHPUnit 9.5.20 and noticed that it is printing `#StandWithUkraine` for every test run. Eg.

```
Testing started at 10:01 am ...
Running in local mode
PHPUnit 9.5.20 #StandWithUkraine


Time: 00:01.141, Memory: 24.00 MB

OK (1 test, 4 assertions)
```

Comment: Is it causing a problem? It seems harmless to me

Comment: @EricStotch Everytime I run a test, my thoughts go to the Ukraine War. I am unable to be fully present when running/fixing my tests.

Comment: 9.5.20 is the latest version - https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit. Prefer to use a stable version rather than master.

Comment: That's a really good reason to not want it. I unfortunately can't help but I'll remember things like this can make it harder for people

Comment: @EricStotch Like an ad, it is not harmless, but your brain records it alot

Answer (score 9):

I guess you would have to edit actual source code of the package, and that seems not recommended.

But the banner is located in `phpunit / src / TextUI / TestRunner.php` on line `322 - 331`

I guess removing it would do the trick, however I haven't tried it and don't recommend.
The banner is also mentioned in a few other files. I've tracked down a commit made by the package author so you can see where the banner is mentioned.
[Commit by author](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/f9b2fc9c67fcc873115598d1d625cb4dcabff8d4)